# Clarification required in Breadth First Search code as output doesn't match my understanding

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I found this code from techiedelight [https://www.techiedelight.com/breadth-first-search/] for BFS

the code is as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Data structure to store graph edges
struct Edge {
    int src, dest;
};

// Class to represent a graph object
class Graph
{
public:
    // construct a vector of vectors to represent an adjacency list
    vector<vector<int>> adjList;

    // Graph Constructor
    Graph(vector<Edge> const &edges, int N)
    {
        // resize the vector to N elements of type vector<int>
        adjList.resize(N);

        // add edges to the undirected graph
        for (auto &edge: edges)
        {
            adjList[edge.src].push_back(edge.dest);
            adjList[edge.dest].push_back(edge.src);
        }
    }
};

// Perform BFS recursively on graph
void recursiveBFS(Graph const &graph, queue<int> &q,
                    vector<bool> &discovered)
{
    if (q.empty())
        return;

    // pop front node from queue and print it
    int v = q.front();
    q.pop();
    cout << v << " ";

    // do for every edge (v -> u)
    for (int u : graph.adjList[v])
    {
        if (!discovered[u])
        {
            // mark it discovered and push it into queue
            discovered[u] = true;
            q.push(u);
        }
    }

    recursiveBFS(graph, q, discovered);
}

// Recursive C++ implementation of Breadth first search
int main()
{
    // vector of graph edges as per above diagram
    vector<Edge> edges = {
        {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {5, 9},
        {5, 10}, {4, 7}, {4, 8}, {7, 11}, {7, 12}
        // vertex 0, 13 and 14 are single nodes
    };

    // Number of nodes in the graph
    int N = 15;

    // create a graph from edges
    Graph graph(edges, N);

    // stores vertex is discovered or not
    vector<bool> discovered(N, false);

    // create a queue used to do BFS
    queue<int> q;

    // Do BFS traversal from all undiscovered nodes to
    // cover all unconnected components of graph
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (discovered[i] == false)
        {
            // mark source vertex as discovered
            discovered[i] = true;

            // push source vertex into the queue
            q.push(i);

            // start BFS traversal from vertex i
            recursiveBFS(graph, q, discovered);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the output I get from this code is as below:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

However, I don't understand how the vertex 0,13 and 14 come into output if it is not there in the graph? In addition, the output for the BFS for this input is different from that of my understanding as per my understanding it should be as below:

```
1 2 3 4 5 7 6 9 10 11 13
```

Can anybody explain if my doubts are correct or wrong? It would be helpful if someone could clarify my doubts.

Comment: The for loop goes from 0 to N(15), so you currently have a very elaborate way of printing all  the nodes in the graph. You could, for example, use union-find to identify clusters of connected nodes instead.

Comment: @Botje is the order(the way in which output is shown) of the graph correct. I understand that the node 13, 14 comes from N = 15. How about the order in which it prints it is correct?

Comment: Looks like it in this case, but you cannot in general rely on the order of nodes in an adjacency list, nor the order of nodes in the graph. That's why I said you're better off doing something useful with the BFS instead of just printing nodes.

Comment: You are performing 4 BFS searches, with roots 0, 1, 13 and 14.  I also think that recursion for BFS is essentially wasted - there is a queue, why is a (program) stack needed there? The main advantage of recursion is, from my point of view, the free stack...

Comment: @tucuxi if I remove the queue from the code how will it be BFS it will then effectively be DFS right?

Comment: If you use a queue, and push newly discovered nodes and pop nodes to visit, you are doing BFS. If you use a stack, and do the same, that will be DFS. If you use neither, and instead rely on recursion, you will also get DFS. Recursion + queues or recursion + stacks does not get you much.